# Get emacs to recognize python3 shebang

Tags: python-3.x, emacs, shebang

I'm using emacs to edit some Python 3 code, but it doesn't provide syntax highlighting when the shebang is `#! /usr/bin/env python3`.  Highlighting works fine with just `#! /usr/bin/env python`.  How do I get emacs to recognize a python3 shebang as a Python file, and provide appropriate syntax highlighting?

Edit: I'm using version 22.1.1, with no ability to change it.

Comment: Have you installed [Emacs Python mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs#toc2)?

Comment: @DYZ `python-mode` is part of emacs

Comment: @jenesaisquoi Only from 24.1 and up.

Comment: @DYZ ah thanks, didnt realize it was that recent

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem you had here and the other answer by Rorschach did not work for me, also because I had an old version (24.3) of emacs which I couldn't upgrade. After trial and error, this worked for me:

Add to your `.emacs` file the line:

```
(push '("python3" . python-mode) interpreter-mode-alist)
```

Old emacs (prior to 24.4) did not support regex for editing interpreter-mode-alist, which was why the other answer's suggested fix did not work.

The changelog for emacs 24.4 mentions the new support for regex: "The cars (sic) of the elements in `interpreter-mode-alist` are now treated as regexps rather than literal strings."

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of `auto-mode-interpreter-regexp`, which should match the shebang entry correctly by default.  Then, ensure there is an entry in your `interpreter-mode-alist` like

```
("python[0-9.]*" . python-mode)
```

If not for some reason, add it in your init file, eg.

```
(cl-pushnew '("python[0-9.]*" . python-mode) interpreter-mode-alist :test #'equal)
```

### Edit

Since your emacs is quite ancient, try

```
(push '("python[0-9.]*" . python-mode) interpreter-mode-alist)
```

Comment: Adding the suggesting line to my init file gives me the following error:

`An error has occured while loading '/Users/[redacted]/.emacs':

Symbol's function definition is void: cl-pushnew`

Comment: are you on a really old emacs?  Try just evaluating `(push '("python[0-9.]*" . python-mode) interpreter-mode-alist)` in your scratch buffer or with `M-:` and check your python file

Comment: I'm stuck with version 22.1.1 - edited my question to include that.